# How to update partial view from another partial view via action results

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have three partial views on main view [image: Something like this]

on the first partial view I have search functionality and when user clicks on search I want to refresh results into 3rd partial view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{  
         virtualmodel vm = new virtualmodel(); 
      return PartialView(svm);

} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(ViewModel svm)
{  
         // Query to retrive the result 
      // I am not sure what to return from here. Link to another action    or just return back to same same partial 

} 

public ActionResult AnotherPartialPartial()
{
}
```

In main view

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("Search", "Searchc");
  }
```

How to do it? Do I need ajax?

Comment: if you don't want to reload whole page - then you need ajax. If it's ok for you - you can just use regular form post

Comment: ajax is the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: most definitely ajax

Comment: Despite some people really tried to help me but still I am not able to find out workable solution :(

Comment: @Nil Did you get it resolved - and if you did what was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using ajax you can call a controller action and return it's response to a particular `div`.

Empty `div`:

```
<div class="row" id="div3">

</div>
```

Ajax to display html in empty `div`:

```
function performSearch(searchCriteria) {
   //get information to pass to controller
   var searchInformation = JSON.stringify(**your search information**);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "ControllerName")',//controller name and action 
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'svm': searchInformation } //information for search
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#div3').html(result); //write returned partial view to empty div
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand what to put next to data

Comment: svm is an object at my action result, do I need to refer to add that object?

Comment: sorry yes, I was trying to make it closer to your problem and I missed that part, updating now

Comment: it looked like your search action was taking svm as a parameter, which is why I put that there.  What is the action you are calling to perform your search, and return the partial view?

Comment: I am calling SearchMenu actionresult to get search result and I am passing that result to ListPartial method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110284/discussion-between-nil-and-rogerdeuce).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will help you with it!
Try to handle submit button onclick event like this:

```
$("#yourButtonId").click(function()
{
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
                url: "/yourUrl", //in asp.net mvc using ActionResult
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
              //Your result is here
              $("#yourContainerId").html(result);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't work for me.My be my button is on partial view and div on main view

Comment: @Nil Try to add load or reload window.reload();  function after  $("#yourContainerId").html(result);  if it helps pls, check up as fixes thanx

Comment: I wrote it like  $("#showFloors").html(result);
                    window.reload(); but still no

Comment: @Nil Here is you may get some information about this solution ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014129/partial-view-refreshes-after-jquery-ajax-post

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ajax.

First, change your html.beginform to ajax.beginform in your view and add div id into **UpdateTargetId** that you want to change contents. After updating first partial with ajax.beginform, you can update other partialviews with ajax.beginform's **"OnSuccess"** function. You have to add update function like that:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", 
        new { /*your objects*/ }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
        UpdateTargetId = "ChangeThisPart", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessMethod" }))
        {
           /*your code*/
        }

<script>
   function OnSuccessMethod() {
      $("#YouWantToChangeSecondDivID").load('/YourController/YourAction2');
      $("#YouWantToChangeThirdDivID").load('/YourController/YourAction3');
   };
</script>
```

Then in your controller, return a partial view to refresh your view part that you entered it's ID in UpdateTargetId value:

```
public ActionResult YourControllerName(YourModelType model)
{
   ...//your code
   return PartialView("_YourPartialViewName", YourViewModel);
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add reference to "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" in your view while using ajax.

Comment: But I have 3 partial views. I want to update 3rd partial for now and later periodically I want to update 2nd partial view, will it still work?

Comment: I have updated my answer for updating multiple partial views.

Comment: Objects? Which object? One which will be passed to controller ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to add additional object to pass to controller, you can add them in that field. But if you don't want it, you don't have to use it.

Comment: I tried something like this "@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchMenu", "Search",
        new { /*your objects*/ }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "ChangeThisPart",
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccessMethod"
        }))
{
   Html.RenderAction("SearchMenu", "Search");

    <div id="abc"></div>
}


<script>
   function OnSuccessMethod() {
      $("#abc").load('/Search/SearchMenu');
      $("#YouWantToChangeThirdDivID").load('/YourController/YourAction3');
   };
</script>" It didn't work tho

Comment: Hello, I am still unable to pass data from view to the controller, can you tell me how to pass that data?

Answer (score 0):

So, say you have your View with PartialView, which have to be updated by button click:

```
<div class="target">
 @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdatePoints");}
</div>

<input class="button" value="update" />
```

There are some ways to do it. For example you may use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $('.button')click(function(){        
            $.post('@Url.Action("PostActionToUpdatePoints", "Home")').always(function(){
                $('.traget').Load('/Home/UpdatePoints');        
            })        
        });
    });        
</script>
```

PostActionToUpdatePoints is your Action with [HttpPost] attribute, which you use to update points

If you use logic in your action UpdatePoints() to update points, maybe you forgot to add [HttpPost] attribute to it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePoints()
{    
    ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points;
    return PartialView("UpdatePoints");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I am trying to do it in this way, but here is a new error now, for @{Html.RenderAction("SearchMenu", "Search");} it gives an error System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper

Comment: I don't know where am I wrong but it says null exception