# Replace a PartialView with another one (ASP NET CORE MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm using ASP NET CORE MVC 5.

I have a View ("ChooseServices") which, depending on the parameter passed, displays 1 or N PartialViews (Forms):

**ChooseServices.cshtml:**

```html
<div class="col">
    @if (Model.OfferServiceA)
    {
        <partial name="_FormA" />
    }

    @if (Model.OfferServiceB)
    {
        <partial name="_FormB" />
    }

    @if (Model.OfferServiceC)
    {
        <partial name="_FormC" />
    }
</div>
```

[image]

After answering each Form individually, I want to display a default message which is another PartialView ("_confirmation.cshtml") in place of the Form.

Something like this:
(after submit Form-A)
[image: after submit Form-A]

(and after submit Form-C)
[image: and after submit Form-C]

In summary, after submitting a Form (partial view), I want it be replaced by another PartialViews, all inside the View "ChooseServices".

---

### **[EDIT - Some code]**

---

CONTROLLER:

```cs
public class SomeServiceController : Controller
{
    // A survey brings to here. 
    public IActionResult ChooseServices(SuggestedServicesDTO dto)
    {
        return View(dto);
    }
}
```

---

VIEWS (ignoring css)

**ChooseServices.cshtml**

```cs
@model SuggestedServicesDTO 

<section >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

                @if (Model.OfferServiceA)
                {
                    <partial name="_FormA" />
                }

                @if (Model.OfferServiceB)
                {
                    <partial name="_FormB" />
                }

                @if (Model.OfferServiceC)
                {
                    <partial name="_FormC" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

**_Form{x}.cshtml**

{x} is the service name.

```html
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>THIS IS THE FORM-{x}.</h3>
            <form asp-action="??IDK what put here">

                <div>
                    <label>Select an option:</label>

                    <!-- Radio buttons Begin --> 
                    <div>
                        <label for="service{x}Opt{N}">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsService{x}" id="service{x}Opt{N}" value="someValue1">
                            <span>Option QWERTY</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="service{x}Opt{N}">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsService{x}" id="service{x}Opt{N}" value="someValue2">
                            <span>Option ASDFGH</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- others options here --> 

                    <!-- Radio buttons end--> 

                </div>



                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit {x}"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

**_Confirmation.cshtml**
(Just a message, nothing important)

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div>
            <h3>Thanks for answering!</h3>

            <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.open('someurl', '_blank').focus();">
                Do something...
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I don't know what to do after submit de Forms{x}.

Comment: Can you show any code in which you've attempted to do this? One idea not know what you are thinking: Wrap each form with a div and give it a unique id. When submitting a Form, use AJAX and capture the wrapper's Id in a variable. Have the AJAX response contain your view. Find the div searching the DOM for the wrapper with the id you captured. Replace that element you find with the response.

Comment: @AnthonySylvia I edited the post (added some code)

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865722/how-to-update-partial-view-from-another-partial-view-via-action-results/36866101) useful to you ?